# Glyph not displayed on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with some programmaticly sortable columns, the sorting itself is done on mouse click.  I can get the gliph direction property but no glyph is displayed.

Any idea why?

```
private void gvRules_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  var column = gvRules.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

  var sortGlyphDirection = column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;

  if (column.SortMode != DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic)
    return;

  switch (sortGlyphDirection)
  {
    case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None:
    case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending:
      gvRules.Sort(column, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
      break;
    case System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending:
      gvRules.Sort(column, ListSortDirection.Descending);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it:

```
private void gvRules_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        // Put each of the columns into programmatic sort mode.
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in ((DataGridView)sender).Columns)
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        }
    }
```

needed to set column.SortMode programatic again

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the SortGlyphDirection **after** set the GridView datasource